# What is the benefit of organic red wine?

Tags: wine

Red wine is a rich wellspring of a polyphenol called resveratrol, which goes about as a cancer prevention agent. It shields the cells of the body from harm and avoids perpetual infections. These cell reinforcements assume a noteworthy part in the anticipation of disease, including colorectal growth and lung malignancy.

Recent studies suggest that resveratrol found in red wine and red grapes may help in preventing age related memory loss.

As indicated by the discoveries of the diary Nature, wine restrains the union of endothelin-1, a supermolecule to blame of the operating of fats on the dividers of veins prompting to arterial sclerosis. Wine, in addition, has giant amounts of procyanidins, a category of phenols. that assume a section within the oxidization of cholesterol, decrease the danger of gas ailments.

What is the benefit of organic red wine over non-organic red wine?

Comment: Do you have a question in your question anywhere?  It reads more like you're providing an answer (which is fine, you can ask and answer at the same time), not asking a question.  Also, the "organic" part doesn't seem to play a role in the rest of the text, is it important or relevant somehow?

Comment: I almost took the question down because confusion, but since there wasn't a similar question posted here I let it go and answered it.

Comment: OK, I spent a lot of time answering this question. I think it's pretty clear what the question is so I "fixed" it! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a little vague. I'm assuming by the nature of your question, you mean the health benefits as opposed to the environmental benefits. Having been growing organic wine grapes for 18 years I think I can address both issues. I might have a more controversial view than most people, but in the end I don't think it makes a lot of difference to drink Organic wine vs. traditional farming from a health perspective.

Grapes are grown, generally, in a dry and hot climate. California, Australia, Spain, Italy. Because of this, there are usually less problems with rot and mildew on grape vines. The two biggest problems are powdery mildew and botrytis. There are some insect problems, but generally they are not a big deal. Compared to other crops like lettuce, strawberries, potatoes, the amount of fertilizer and spraying is minimal.

So, what I am trying to say is that amount of chemicals sprayed on grapevines is already at a low level compared to many other foods you might consume. Here is my controversial take on Organic vs. Traditional wine making. Growers will actually spray MORE chemicals on their grapes they are just "organic" just because the Organic chemicals are not as effective. That means more tractors, more people contributing to pollution in and around the vineyard.

On top of that, in the USA, "[Organic Wine](https://www.ttb.gov/pdf/wine-labeling-guide.pdf)" is different than in Europe. In Europe, it means that grapes were grown organically. In the USA, it means that they were grown organically AND do not use sulfites. Which the Europeans have known to help preserve wine for thousands of years and are naturally occurring during the fermentation process. (BTW, sulfites are also a nasty chemical in large amounts). There are way more sulfites on your pre-packaged salad and raisins than there are in wine.

REMEMBER, you are consuming a beverage that contains about 14% of a known carcinogen, namely Ethanol. So expecting your drink to have these huge health benefits is kind of a false flag.

You have to ask yourself why there isn't a lot more Organic wine on the market? A fellow grower told me that it doesn't make economical sense. It costs way more money to grow them vs. traditional or just grow Organic grapes and not have to do all the record keeping, which takes a lot of time and money. High quality growers, for the most part are a thoughtful bunch and really don't want to spray non-organic chemicals and winemakers use non-organic chemicals in the winery.

So, here is my recommendation. I really don't think there is a huge environmental or health edge for Organic wine. High volume, low priced wines will generally have more chemicals in them. If you can find an Organic red wine that you like and you can afford, got for it. If you can spend a little more money, say $20 or more for a bottle of wine, those wines probably came from grapes that were babied way more than a box wine grapes and probably have less chemicals in them in general. In fact as you go up the price curve it's generally known they have less and less chemical inputs. So, the more you can spend, the less chemicals will probably be in your wine.

(And to blow your mind, many wines are not vegetarian! And you have no way to find out.)

Comment: Why would a wine no be vegetarian‽

Comment: There are at least to things that winemakers put into wine that are made of animals. Egg whites to help clarify the wine. Isinglass which is a fish swim bladder and does the same thing as egg whites.

Comment: Isn't there an Italian drink where eggs are added to wine? They call it something other than _vino_. Perhaps the quantity of eggs you're speaking of is very small?

Comment: http://www.italyheritage.com/traditions/food/vov.htm

Answer (score -1):

Organic wine gives you no hangover! That much i can tell you from personal experience. I do live on an allover organic diet and love red wine, so naturally that is all i drink. I live in Europe and have visited quite a few organic wineries. The benefits become apparent when you talk to these people who tend to their vines personally day in and day out. The output of wine is not sure from year to year, since they can not rely on pesticides to guaranty output. The benefits are in the taste, environmental support, personal well being and knowledge that you drink something which was made with heart and soul.

Comment: Simply not true. I've had plenty of hangovers from organic wine. Go drink a couple of bottles of red Organic wine in a night and get back to me. Plus the labeling requirements in the USA are screwed up and you could be drinking an organic wine and not know it.

Comment: So everybody is different. I have had 1 to 1.5 bottles of organic red wine per night and never had a hangover, not true for me with not organic wine and same quantity. Personal experience is different for everybody. True on the labeling, some wineries can not afford to get certified but still grow and produce organic wine. A good wine store knows these things and can point you in the right direction, which is true for Europe and the States.